# How to get a background image to extend full width when using a grid?

Tags: css, grid, sass, background-image

Is it possible to have a wrapper element's background image extend beyond the grid while keeping things responsive?

I am able to do it with a solid color using the box shadow technique, but I haven't been able to get the background image to break out of the grid.

I'm using a 12 column flexible, percentage based grid that has a max width of 1140px and floats the columns. Setting the background image of the wrapping element ends up at 1140px unless I gave the element an absolute width (like 150%) which breaks the responsiveness and I'm pretty sure is bad practice anyway.

My layout is simple, something like this

```
<body>
    <container>
        <header></header>
        <inner-content>
            <grid-element-one></div>
            <bg-wrap>
                <grid-element-two></div>
            </div>
            <grid-element-three></div>
        </inner-content>
        <footer></footer>
    </container>
</body>
```

And it's laid out where the element that I need to have the background-image is in between other gridded sections. So I can't just put it above the footer or something and have the grid end before it's affected.

The css is also bare bones.

```
.inner-content {
    max-width: 1140px; /* when 768px+, otherwise 96% */
}
.element-two {
    color: $font-color;
    background-color: $bg-gray;
    box-shadow: -25rem 0 0 $bg-gray, 25rem 0 0 $bg-gray;
    height: 475px;
}
.bg-wrap {
    background: url(../images/bg/texture.png) 0 80px repeat;            
}
```

Comment: I was thinking a pseudo element, like :before might do it, but I've got limited experience using them and am not sure how to write it.

Comment: Is it possible for you to plz create a fiddle to have a look at what exactly you want?

Comment: @ajc - here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mPGQQ/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ? http://jsfiddle.net/mPGQQ/7/

If yes you have to move the end of your `div class="inner-content"` to the end, and modify the css for `.inner-content` as in the fiddle.

Hope this helps

Cheers

Comment: Not exactly. I only want the background to apply to one div. Like this, but where it is blue, I want to be able to use a bg image: http://jsfiddle.net/jackiesc/mPGQQ/8/

Comment: Also, because everything is on the same grid, I cannot just move the inner-content div around without making everything else get skewed.

Comment: OK, is this one good enough for your needs http://jsfiddle.net/mPGQQ/35/ ? You may have ot play with percentages or sizes but I think that's pretty close of the result you expect..